# Can the "edited" information always be kept to the left of the post owner's information?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design

## [tl;dr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tl;dr#Phrase):

Could the "edited" information be kept to the left of the post owner information (instead of reflowing to be above it) until it's too narrow to fit?

If not, could the 32x32 px `div` for the profile image be hidden when it doesn't contain an image (when the post owner was the editor)?

Doing either would allow more information to be shown on the screen at a time.

---

This is a usability issue on mobile devices or narrow/landscape screens. I have taken screenshots of the question [*Best practice for writing big files*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53665442/1364007) for the examples below. For consistency, the screenshots are all 350px high.

At 1100px wide (adverts redacted), the information displays nicely. Note that the "edited" information is displayed to the left of the post owner information:

> [image]
>
> [image]

At 900px wide, the "edited" information moves to above the information of the post owner, but there is still space to display the information in the original place:

> [image]
>
> [image]

At a very narrow 500px, there is *still* space to have the "edited" information in the original place:

> [image]
>
> [image]

The `div` for the edit information has an empty 32x32 pixel `div` for the self-edited posts:

> [image]

Could this be fixed please?

Comment: The low resolution layouts haven't really had much thought put into them yet. When the announced the network redesign on MSE, I pointed out a glaring problem or two, such as the right sidebar just being shoved underneath the main content body ignominiously. It still does that today.

Comment: It might just be for me, but on my laptop the "edited" section jumps above the original poster around 779px: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qac8Q.gif

Comment: @James the jumping happens depending on what links you have (share/edit/close/delete/flag). Try the same in a private browsing window and you should see it's not at 779px.

Comment: @WaiHaLee true, it breaks at 1119/1120 when I open this page in an incognito window. Hadn't considered that.

Comment: @Jeremy - that *is* how it appears in the proper Mobile view (using the link at the bottom of each page), e.g. [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vbKQ.png). In other words, when the screen is narrow the editor appears first, on the mobile view the editor appears second.

Comment: Seems like we could sacrifice the fact that the links are in the same "row" as the information boxes at small sizes. Just bring the two boxes below the links at those sizes, then they can stay next to each other. That would mean altering their HTML, or their choice of making the wrapper of all three a grid.

Comment: This is worse on small devices such as phones and tablets. The page ends up being much more vertically extended than horizontally.

Comment: Yeah - I know. :(  I spend lots of time on Stack Overflow on my phone (1920x1080 screen). It can be... difficult.